# Base 64 decode + encode yields diffrent results

Tags: java, base64

I'm given a base64 string (I've no control over what string I'm given):
    `PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+CjxzYW1scDpSZXNwb25zZSB4bWxuczpzYW1scD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOnByb3RvY29sIg==`

When I decode it, in Java, it yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
```

When I base64 encode that (again, in Java) it yields:

`PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+DQo8c2FtbHA6UmVzcG9uc2UgeG1sbnM6c2FtbHA9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpwcm90b2NvbCI=`

These strings are different, but they should be the same.

During my search I stumbled upon this site here: https://www.base64encode.org

While on this site, if I click the encode button I get the same results as my java base64 encode.

However, if instead of hitting the encode button, I click on the "Live Mode On" button, I get the original base64-encoded string I received--which is exactly what I want!

Any idea how I can achieve these same results in my own code?

```
public String getEncodedSAMLMessage(String message) {
    byte[] byteMessage;
    try {
        byteMessage = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String base64Encoded = helpers.base64Encode(byteMessage);
        return URLEncoder.encode(base64Encoded, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    }
    return null;
}

public String getDecodedSAMLMessage(String message) {
    String urlDecoded = helpers.urlDecode(message);
    byte[] base64Decoded = helpers.base64Decode(urlDecoded);
    try {
        return new String(base64Decoded, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Provide your code please?

Comment: Newline issue. The incoming string has `\n`, the outgoing one has `\r\n`. Either your encoding or decoding API is changing unix line endings to windows; check the API you're using to see if there's a way to not convert.

Comment: Kevin - I think you are right, can you give me a suggestion on how to fix this in java - see above edited code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Apache Commons Codec.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.Charsets;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;  

public class Base64Encoder {

    private Base64 b64 = new Base64();

    public String encode(String message) {
        return b64.encodeAsString(message.getBytes());
    }

    public String decode(String message) {
        return new String(b64.decode(message), Charsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```